# hiding div javascript (vanilla) cookie

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide a div with javascript and store that information for the rest of the session. Closing the div isnt a problem but somehow the information isnt stored in my cookie.. this is what i have so far.

```
var p = document.getElementById ('pcontainer');
window.onload = function () {
    if(document.cookie.length != 0){
        var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");
        p.style.display = nameValueArray[1];
    }
}


function popup(){
    if(p.style.display != 'none'){
    var none = 'none';
    p.style.display = none;


   document.cookie = "geenpopup=" + none;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a cookie, you can use `document.cookie = "name=value";`, but to retrieve a cookie, you should do something like splitting the cookie by semi-colons, then find your variable name in the array of values. Something like this function:

```
function getCookie (name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

This function copied (and translated to vanilla JS) from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#ajax).

So in your case, you could get the value with `getCookie('geenpopup')` [sic];